# What is use of varchar output parameter in stored procedure - cannot 'return @myvarchar' but can 'select @myvarchar'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, output-parameter

xample:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Delete (@p1 INT, @p2 VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT)
AS
    --@p1 will have calculations done and get a value for @p2
    SET @p2 = 'test'
    RETURN @p2
```

Test:

```
DECLARE @p2 VARCHAR(100)
EXEC sp_Delete
     @p1 = N'1',
     @p2 = N''
```

Error:

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test' to data type int.
```

BUT
you can do this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Delete (@p1 INT)
AS
    --@p1 will have calculations done and get a value for @p2
    SELECT 'test'


    EXEC sp_Delete
         @p1 = N'1'
```

So my question is, what is the use of having a OUTPUT parameter of type varchar (note I'm not questioning an output parameter of type int), when you can't use "return @myvar" if it is a varchar. You can just "select @myvar".
I am trying to figure out what I am doing wrong, because I think I don't understand the use of a specific varchar output variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the two things, RETURN value and OUTPUT parameters.

RETURN is the "overall" status of the sp execution, whereas OUTPUT parameters allow you to send back multiple values calculated in your procedure.

Also, for OUTPUT parameters to send back their value, you should specify the OUTPUT keyword

```
declare @p2 varchar(100)
exec sp_Delete
@p1=N'1',
@p2=@p2 OUTPUT -- first @p2 is then sp_parameter name, second is the @p2 variable from you outer batch

select @p2
```

You can mix RETURN values with OUTPUT parameters

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestProc
@P1 INT, 
@P2 VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
   SET @P2='SOME VALUE'
   RETURN @P1
END
GO
DECLARE @R INT, @P VARCHAR(10)
EXEC @R=TestProc @P1=1, @P2=@P OUT --OUT is short for OUTPUT, you can use either one
SELECT @R, @P

-----------------
1, 'SOME VALUE'
```

Without using the OUTPUT keywourd  you'll have

```
DECLARE @R INT, @P VARCHAR(10)
EXEC @R=TestProc @P1=1, @P2=@P -- notice the missing OUTPUT
SELECT @R, @P --was not assigned in this batch so is NULL

-----------------
1, NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

An output variable is different from a return value.  The return value is always an integer.  You can retrieve it like:

```
exec @retval = dbo.MyStoredProcedure
```

While an output parameter is retrieved like:

```
exec dbo.MyStoredProcedure @par_out output
```

In your case, omit the `return` statement.  `set @par_out = 'value'` is enough to return the output parameter to the calling code.

Comment: when I try this exec sp_Delete @p1=N'1', @p2 output, I get the message Must declare the scalar variable "@p2".

Comment: Then declare the variable, f.e. `declare @x varchar(50); exec sp_Delete @p1=N'1', @p2=@x output;`

Answer (score 4):

[`RETURN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx) can return only `int` values. Your don't need to use `RETURN`, actually, just omit it:

```
 create PROCEDURE dbo.sp_Delete (
@p1 int,
@p2 varchar(10) OUTPUT
)
AS
--@p1 will have calculations done and get a value for @p2
set @p2 = 'test'
```

...

```
declare @p1 int, @p2 varchar(100)
SELECT @p2 = '', @p1 = 1
exec sp_Delete
@p1,
@p2 OUTPUT

select @p2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set

```
declare
 @variable_name datatype
begin
 set @variable_name= (select query)
end
```

Don't use a return statement  to return a `varchar` value

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. This question is asked more than 10 years ago and it has an accepted answer. Please add some details about the reason you are adding a new answer.